# SQL Server - Partial String match - two columns of different tables

Tags: sql-server, partial, string-matching

I am in need of a query (or stored procedure rather) for SQL Server wherein I need compare data of two different tables with the following structure

**Table 1**

```
ID       Text       Table2ID
1        Chris   
2        John
3        Paul
```

**Table2**

```
ID       Text
1        Mitchell Johnson
2        Chris Martin
3        Steven
```

By comparing the above two tables, I need to get the 'IDs' from table2 and insert them into the 'Table2ID' column of first table

**Comparison criteria:-**

The full word in 'Text' column of 'Table1' should be contained in 'Text' column of 'Table2'

In our case, we would obtain 'IDs' of first two rows from table2 (since the word John is contained in 'Mitchell Johnson' and the word Chris is contained in 'Chris Martin' and Paul is not contained in 'Table2')

How could I achieve this? It would be nice if someone out here is able to shed light on my path

Regards,
Raghuraman.V

Comment: How would you propose handling a double match, i.e. if you had "Chris Johnson" how would you treat it?

Comment: @RedFilter - something very similar has bitten me in the rear before on a similar process :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The abstract answer is:

```
UPDATE Table
SET Table.col1 = other_table.col1
FROM Table
INNER JOIN other_table ON Table.id = other_table.id
```

Specifically:

```
update Table1
set Table1.Table2ID = Table2.ID
from Table1
inner join Table2 on Table2.Text like '%' + Table1.Text + '%'
```

Comment: What do you mean by `abstract answer`?

Comment: Abstract meaning not specific to your case, a generalized answer. It is the pattern you can use the next time you need to do an `UPDATE FROM` type of query.

Comment: Out of curiosity (if table2 also contained the record `4 | John Smith`) would you guess that that `table1.table2Id` would equal 1 or 4?

Comment: I have a row with '#WALT DISNEY' in table1 and similarly a row with '#DISNEY WORLD' in table2. Your query doesn't treat it as a match. I hope you get my point

Comment: @Conrad: I would guess we can't know for sure, since record order is indeterminate in SQL without an `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: @Raghu: You just radically changed the scope of your question.

Comment: @Raghu - this is not even close to what you asked originally.  Also that is a big issue in  your data structure if you need SQL to break out substrings for comparison for a join condition like that...